# Using breakpoint in eclipse for servlet program

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I got a problem using beakpoint. there are many discussed topic regarding my question. but all of them are about java program( where main() is declared) but for servlet program how to use breakpoint? i am using elcipse IDE galileo version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you let Eclipse start the web container in debug mode, and you use the breakpoint exactly like you would do on a standalone application, or you start the container in debug mode from outside of eclipse, and define (and start) a debug configuration in eclipse which connects to the remote debugging session of the container.

The way to start the container in debug mode, and the port to use to connect the debugger to the server, depends on the container. Read its documentation.

Whatever the way you choose, you'll have to use your webapp (using your browser, for example), until a request is sent to your servlet and the line with the breakpoint is executed. At this point, the way to debug is exactly the same way as if you debugged a standalone application.